# ¿Cómo crear fragmentos "snippets" de HTML en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html5

Trato de crear fragmentos de estructuras HTML, pero no sé cómo hacerlo en Visual Studio Code.

Intento, pero no se cómo hacerlo y en el archivo `.json` no dice como hacerlo ni esta [página tampoco](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_common-questions)

Comment: feel free to ask here, but it has to be in Spanish, if you want to ask in English, you have -> http://stackoverflow.com/ good luck

Comment: creo que el usuario se refiere, a esto, por ejemplo yo en mi editor pongo ht y tab, y se crea la estructura basica te crea el body, el head el DOC ect, por si ayuda a alguien a crear una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Lo sé pero me refiero a como crearlos como tal en VS Code.

Comment: creo que en este video puedes ver si entiendo bien a que te refieres, es sobre el minuto 27:00 pero no se si tienes que configurar algo, miralo igual te ayuda ->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WyJibE3ZK0

Comment: @AngelAngel  lo que comenta el video que has propuesto es sobre Zen Coding   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmet_%28software%29 tambien se lo menciona como Emmet  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html   pero no creo que sea eso a lo que se refiere, sino crear snippets custom de codigo

Comment: cuando creas el json con el snippet donde lo ubicas ? porque en el link que has puesto menciona lugares concretos donde ubicarlos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini yo es que la pregunta estaba media en ingles media en español, pero un una parte decia -> I try to create snippets for basic HTML... y pensaba que el usuario buscaba eso y deje un comentario, pero veo ahora que lo que quiere es crear su propio snippets si entiendo bien. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel  si imagine que despues de la traduccion podia causar alguna confusion, mas que nada porque hasta ahora con el VS los snippet solo se podria crear para codigo .net, pero con VS Code tambien se puede crear en html

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por la info, ademas gracias a tus comentarios creo que, queda mas claro lo que el usuario preguntaba acabo de editar la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias por responder! Pero creo que no me supe dar a entender.. Efectivamente, quiero crear mis propios snippets como en Atom, SublimeText, etc. Pero no logro hacerlo en HTML. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_common-questions En esa pagina se muestra como debo hacerlo pero no con HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Dentro de su VSCode realice lo siguiente:

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>User Snippets</kbd>

le aparecera un lugar donde escribir que pone `Selet lenguaje for Snippets`
en su caso escribir `HTML` se creara un fichero (de no existir) con el nombre de `html.json` (donde html cambiara dependiendo del tipo selecionado anteriormente) en algun lugar como:

`../config/Code/User/snippets` "dependera de en que OS este usando, puede que `config` este oculta o con otro nombre, asi como la compilacion del mismo, o si es el binario de Microsoft puede que este cambie".

A la vez tambien se abrira en el editor con un ejemplo comentado entre `{ }` 
si no se le abriera por cualquier circunstancia puede buscar el fichero en la ruta mencionada anteriormente.

---

html.json que se le muestra

```
{
    /*
         // Place your snippets for HTML here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
         // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
         // $1, $2 for tab stops, ${id} and ${id:label} and ${1:label} for variables. Variables with the same id are connected.
         // Example:
         "Print to console": {
            "prefix": "log",
            "body": [
                "console.log('$1');",
                "$2"
            ],
            "description": "Log output to console"
        }
    */
}
```

---

copie este ejemplo dentro del fichero `html.json`

```
   "HTMLTets": {
        "prefix": "htmlBase",
        "body": [
            "<!doctype html>",
                "\t<html lang=\"$1\">",
                   "\t\t<head> ",
                   "\t\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",
                   "\t\t\t<title>$2</title>",
                   "\t\t</head>",

                   "\t\t<body>",

                   "\t\t</body>",
                "\t</html>"       
        ],
        "description": "Es un test html"
    }
```

html.json file

```
{
/*
     // Place your snippets for HTML here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
     // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
     // $1, $2 for tab stops, ${id} and ${id:label} and ${1:label} for variables. Variables with the same id are connected.
     // Example:
     "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    }
*/
    "HTMLTets": {
        "prefix": "htmlBase",
        "body": [
            "<!doctype html>",
                "\t<html lang=\"$1\">",
                   "\t\t<head> ",
                   "\t\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",
                   "\t\t\t<title>$2</title>",
                   "\t\t</head>",

                   "\t\t<body>",

                   "\t\t</body>",
                "\t</html>"       
        ],
        "description": "Es un test html"
    }
}
```

---

guarde el fichero, cree un nuevo documento con la extension `.html` ahora si escribe `html` se le aparecera una lista en la cual podra elegir el Snippets. Espero ayude.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets

P.D: Si tiene dificultades para encontrar el directorio que como se le indica anteriormente puede hacer una busqueda con este nombre `html.json` y de esta manera podra ver en que lugar fue creado, si existen varios resultados busque el que mas se asemeje a la ruta mencionada.

Comment: muchas gracias! Tuve que hacer otras cosas para que me pudiera funcionar :D

Answer (score 1):

Del artículo que mencionas

[Adding Snippets to Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets)

Hay una sección que es importante

> To open up a snippet file for editing, open `User Snippets` under `File`, `Preferences` and select the language for which the snippets should appear.

para registrar el snippet que estas creando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudiste crear el snippet creo que es el paso que te esta faltando

Comment: Exacto jajaja no sé como hacerlo! Se donde se alojan pero la estructura en el archivo .json para los snippets no se muestra como seria un ejemplo para HTML.

Comment: o sea, puedes crear el snippet y desde el intellisense del VS lo reconoce ? o tienes problemas en definir la estructura html dentro del json? hay algo en la frase cuando te explicas que no queda claro

Comment: Mi problema es definir la estructura del json para crear el snippet. Por ejemplo la estructura básica del una página web en HTML. Lo he logrado en Atom y el Sublime pero en Code no.

Comment: Aconsejaria que edites la pregunta y plantees de forma correcta el problema, si ya tienes un snippet creado deberias poner el codigo. Ademas un detalle el snippet se supone que es para representar una parte o seccion de codigo, no toda una pagina, para eso se usan layout de asp.net mvc  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look

Comment: Voy a remplantear la pregunta. Yo solo quiero saber cual es la estructura de un snippet de HTML en VS Code. Yo sé la estructura de una página web. Sólo quiero saber como estructurarlo en el .json para luego usar ese snippet.